# Print preview words split to different page

Tags: html, css, printing, paragraph

I use <p> tag to display the information and when print preview it, words are split into another page. Is there a way to prevent it? Sample below:

[image: Words in end of page continues to next page]

Answer (score 0):

add this to div that contains printable items:

```
@media print  
{
    div{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

*Current browser support:

> Chrome - 1.0+
>
> Firefox (Gecko) - 19.0+
>
> Internet Explorer - 8.0+
>
> Opera - 7.0+
>
> Safari - 1.3+ (312)

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for sharing the answer but I have already tried it and didn't work for me.

Comment: Try not to use p tags, use span or directly into a div instead and let's see what happen (adding, of course overflow-wrap: break-word; and the media pasted on the answer).

Comment: Finally, I found out it's due to the footer css style I was using. Thanks for help Joel.

Comment: that's the reason for what is better to add code snippets instead pasting code =D

you're welcome, and have a nice day!